# changing/updating app with mouse click - kivy

Tags: kivy

I'm working on a mobile app for the first time with Kivy. I've made some progress and I would like to have a "Main" page that shows up before anything else. The user would then press a button and the page would change to something a little more useful.

At the moment I get a giant button and when I click on it nothing happens...

I'm new to kivy and any help would be awesome.

I've tried to comment my code with what I "think" is happening.

```py
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.carousel import Carousel
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.graphics import Color
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.graphics.instructions import CanvasBase

CAROUSEL_OUTPUT = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        #for starters just show a big button that will call
        #showData when clicked.
        b = Button(text='Click Me!!!')
        self.layout = GridLayout(cols=1,rows=4,spacing=[2,0])
        self.layout.add_widget(b)
        #i pass the layout thinking that i can it
        #not sure what i need to change to make it work
        b.bind(on_press=(lambda e=1:self.showData(self.layout)))        
        return self.layout

    def showData(self,layout):
        self.Money = []
        self.Trip = []
        self.Gals = []
        #set up the local layout
        layout = GridLayout(cols=1,rows=4,spacing=[2,0])
        row1 = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        row2 = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        row3 = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        w = self.makeCarousels(6,4,1)
        l = Label(text='Please enter the total amount paid.')
        row1.add_widget(l)
        row1.add_widget(w)
        layout.add_widget(row1)
        w = self.makeCarousels(7,3,2)
        l = Label(text='Please enter the total amount of gallons of gasoline purchased.')
        row2.add_widget(l)
        row2.add_widget(w)
        layout.add_widget(row2)
        w = self.makeCarousels(5,4,3)
        b = Button(text='Click Me!!!')
        b.bind(on_press=(lambda e=1: self.printCindexes()))
        l = Label(text='Please enter the miles driven on your last tank.(Trip)')
        row3.add_widget(l)
        row3.add_widget(w)
        layout.add_widget(row3)
        layout.add_widget(b)
        self.layout = layout
        return layout

    def makeCarousels(self,numOfCarous,placeHolder,row):
        #this function just makes numOfCarous carousels
        #and puts a '.' at placeHolder
        check = False
        layout = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal')
        for i in range(0,numOfCarous):
            if i == (placeHolder - 1):
                check = True
                c = Carousel(direction = 'top')
            else:
                c = Carousel(direction = 'top')
            if row == 1:
                self.Money.append(c)
            elif row == 2:
                self.Gals.append(c)
            elif row == 3:
                self.Trip.append(c)
            for num in CAROUSEL_OUTPUT:
                l = Label(text=str(num))
            c.add_widget(l)
        if check:
            l = Label(text='.')
            layout.add_widget(c)
            layout.add_widget(l)
            check = False
        else:           
            layout.add_widget(c)                
        return layout

    def printCindexes(self):
        self.calculateValues(self.Money,4,1)
        self.calculateValues(self.Gals,3,2)
        self.calculateValues(self.Trip,4,3)
        print '\n'

    def calculateValues(self,list,placeHolder,row):
        numOfEntries = len(list)
        total = 0.0
                factor = 1.0
        for n in range(0,placeHolder-1):
            factor=factor*10.0
        for n in list:
            total += factor*n.index
            factor = factor/10.0
        if row == 1:
            print 'Total Paid: $%6.2f' %(total)
        elif row == 2:
            print 'Total Gallons: %7.4f gallons' %(total)
        elif row == 3:
            print 'Total Trip: %5.1f miles' %(total)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Thanks again everyone!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fifth line of your showData method is `layout = GridLayout(cols=1,rows=4,spacing=[2,0])`. This *overrides* the variable 'layout' that you passed to the function - python forgets that first `layout` variable existed and only knows about the new GridLayout you just created. After this everything gets added to the new layout just fine but you don't then tell kivy to do anything with it.

If you just delete that line, all the new layouts get added to your root layout just like you want, and the visible homescreen is updated to show them.

So...that should fix your general problem, but the general structure seems a bit non-ideal. Why not make a new class, something like `class HomeGrid(GridLayout):`, then give this class the methods you want to alter itself like `showData`. That way you don't have to keep track of class variables and pass them around, you're properly associating the object transformation with the object itself.

I also strongly recommend reading about kivy language, which really does make much of layout design very easy. You can make the basic templates for your widgets there very easily, rather than messing around with stuff like `b.bind` that quickly becomes unwieldy once you're binding many functions.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot agree more with @inclement. You should use the [Kivy Language](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html). I suggest you to use the [ScreenManager](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html). Below I am posting a simplified example of a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17428320/kivy-input-values-for-simple-calculations/17438904#17438904) I gave. notice that you can have as many screens as you want and swap between using the property    `current`:

```
on_press: root.current = 'screen2'
```

The [properties](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.properties.html?highlight=properties#kivy.properties) (or [here](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/events.html#introduction-to-properties)) of Kivy are more than simple attributes. They trigger events that are use to keep the interface up to date. You can also use the Kivy Language to bind your events as @inclement pointed out. You just need to do something like this to call a method that is defined in the `Calc` class:

```
on_press: root.product(*args)
```

Or even executed in the Kivy Language if it is not to complicated.

```
on_press: _result.text = str(int(_a.text) + int(_b.text))
```

Here is the code of something similar you are trying to achieve:

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager

Builder.load_string("""
<Calc@ScreenManager>:
    a: _a
    b: _b
    result: _result
    Screen:
        name: 'screen1'
        Button:
            size_hint: .3,.1
            center: self.parent.center
            text: 'Go to Screen 2'
            on_press: root.current = 'screen2'
    Screen:
        name: 'screen2'
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            Label:
                text: 'Value 1'
            TextInput:
                id: _a
                text: '3'
            Label:
                text: 'Value 2'
            TextInput:
                id: _b
                text: '5'
            Label:
                text: 'Result'
            Label:
                id: _result
            Button:
                text: 'sum'
                # You can do the opertion directly
                on_press: _result.text = str(int(_a.text) + int(_b.text))
            Button:
                text: 'product'
                # Or you can call a method from the root class (instance of calc)
                on_press: root.product(*args)
            Button:
                text: 'Go to Screen 1'
                on_press: root.current = 'screen1'
""")

class Calc(ScreenManager):
    # define the multiplication of a function
    def product(self, instance):
        # self.result, self.a and self.b where defined explicitely in the kv
        self.result.text = str(int(self.a.text) * int(self.b.text))

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Calc()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```